# google mod_pagespeed on python 2.4?

Tags: python, mod-pagespeed

My website runs on python 2.4.3 ,django  1.3, apache 2.3 and centos5.

I want to use google mod_pagespeed for my site.

In the wiki page it says like

"To build on CentOS 5.4, you must install Python 2.6. You don't need to replace the system-provided Python 2.4 -- you just need to have "which python" point to python 2.6"

[wiki link](http://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/wiki/HowToBuild)

What does it means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to have python 2.6 in your path if/when you are building mod_pagesepeed from source.  It doesn't need to be in the path when you are running the your server.

mod_pagespeed does not use Python at runtime.  It only uses it at build time.

If you are using CentOS you can also just download the binary distribution from http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html